# Angularjs: How to prevent creating multiple event listener on controller refresh

Tags: angularjs, listener

I have a **controller** like this:

```
myApp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location){

    console.log('check 1');

    // before route update
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event){
        if($location.path() == "/login"){
            console.log('check 2');
        }
    });

}]);
```

First time `check 1` will be logged and When i click on `/login` link, `check 2` will be logged. everytime i change path to /home and /login, i expect a new `check 2` on console but  what i see **in console** is like this:

```
check 2 (1 time)
check 2 (2 times)
check 2 (3 times)
check 2 (4 times)
...
```

this means by every location change, angularjs creates a new listener and number of `check 2`'s increases!
Is there a **standard** way for listening on location change without this issue? or should i remove my listener before leaving `/login` page?

---

**OTHER FILES**

**my app.js file:**

```
...
when('/login', {
  templateUrl: 'page/login.html', 
  controller: 'loginCtrl', 
  reloadOnSearch: false
})
...
```

**login template:**

```
<section class="login-page section">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    ...
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are subscribing with `$rootScope.$on` in your controller. When you subscribe this way, AngularJS has no chance to clean up the listeners for you when your local `$scope` is destroyed.

Just subscribe with `$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', fn);` If you subscribe this way AngularJS will automatically remove the listener when your local `$scope` is destroyed.

Comment: What about if you are subscribing to an event not generated by AngularJS? E.g. Parsley generates events to which one subscribes using $.listen. This will register a listener each time one hits the controller.